# Can't figure out Discord Increments

Tags: javascript, increment, discord

I'm like, a huge JavaScript noob and I can't figure out how to make an increment work.

Currently my code looks like:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!')
}

var i = 0;

if (msg.content === '+1') {
    msg.reply("Counter: " +i)
}
})
```

Currently, when I type "+1" in my server, it just states what 'i' is. I'd like to know how to make it so every time I enter in +1, it adds up every time.

Comment: msg.reply("Counter: " ++i) would do the increment and typecasting both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resetting the value of `i` back to zero every time your message callback fires. Instead, you can declare `i` as a global variable, and then increment it in your if statement like so:

```
var i = 0; // declare outside (to avoid resetting it)
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
      msg.reply('Pong!')
  }

  if (msg.content === '+1') {
      msg.reply("Counter: " +i)
      i++; // increment the value of i (same as i = i + 1)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it.
Here are some examples.

```
1.
if (msg.content === '+1') {
    i = i + 1
    msg.reply("Counter: " +i)
}

2.
if (msg.content === '+1') {
    i++
    msg.reply("Counter: " +i)
}

3.
if (msg.content === '+1') {
    ++i
    msg.reply("Counter: " +i)
}
```